# Spotfire Custom Expression getting addition of the value from columns

Tags: spotfire

In Spotfire I have 8 different calculated columns 
Example [Column1] has all the values returning as  79'[Column2] has all the values as  48,[Column3] has all the values as  24,[Column4]has all the values as  31,[Column5] has all the values as 9,[Column6]has all the values as  8,[Column7]has all the values as  64,[Column8]has all the values as  32

**the result should be [column1]+[column2]+[column3]+[column4]+[column6]+[column7]+[column8]**
**result should be 294**
 **Help me in writing a custom expression**

Comment: 79+48+24+31+9+8+64+32 = 295. Also, is there not a reason that you cannot sum those columns up in another column? I am confused what the problem is.

Comment: if we do sum it is summing up all the column values. That is if column1 has like 100 rowns and all the values are having 79 it doing sum of those all @MarkP.

Comment: If all of the values are the same, use Max() instead of Sum() as your aggregation method.

Comment: even if I use max when I am filtering by org there is not change at all it is constantly displaying 295 @MarkP.

Comment: 79+48+24+31+9+8+64+32 = 295. What result are you expecting if all the columns show the same numbers across all rows?

Comment: The result should 295 only . when When I change any filters , for suppose if the colnmn1 values changes to 50 , then the result should be 266 right, but If I use max or First result is not changing accordingly @MarkP.

Comment: Can you post an example dxp in Tibco Answers ?  From your question not sure if you are tyring to add another calculated column or trying to write an expression for a visual and if so what type of visual. If using a cross table you could use the column/row to display totals and change the calulation from underlying values to displayed values

Answer (score 0):

Spotfire calculations work down columns.  The expression Sum([Column Name]) will return the same value repeated across all rows.  In order to slice and dice down columns you have to use over and node navigation.  Sum([Column Name]) over ([Date]), for example.

Furthermore, Spotfire calculations do not respond to filtering.  They always take into account the entire data set.